# MySQL Stored Procedure Syntax Errors

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I'm very new to MySQL (and databases in general) and have been tasked with making a stored procedure that will accept a varchar as a parameter to be used as a keyword search from 2 columns of a table.

I'm not familiar with the syntax and searching the internet hasn't been as fruitfull as desired. This is what I came up with:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_Search
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_Search (IN word varchar(100))
BEGIN
SELECT Section.Name 
FROM Section inner join DetailsMats ON Section.NumSection=DetailsMats.NumSection 
WHERE DetailsMats.TechName or DetailsMats.GenName LIKE %word%;
END//
```

Just wondering if I'm doing something disgustingly wrong here or if I'm on the right path. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two errors in your code:

1. Missing delimiter `//` after `DROP PROCEDURE ...`
2. LIKE expression must by string. I use `CONCAT('%', word, '%')` to get string with `word` and `'%'`

Corrected code:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_Search //  -- delimiter here

CREATE PROCEDURE proc_Search (IN word varchar(100))
BEGIN
SELECT Section.Name 
FROM Section inner join DetailsMats ON Section.NumSection=DetailsMats.NumSection 
WHERE DetailsMats.TechName or DetailsMats.GenName LIKE CONCAT('%', word, '%');
END
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems should be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE (Column1 LIKE '%keyword1%' OR Column2 LIKE '%keyword1%') 
      AND (Column1 LIKE '%keyword2%' OR Column2 LIKE '%keyword2%');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use concat to escape the % character.
   Happy coding :)

`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_Search
    CREATE PROCEDURE proc_Search (IN word varchar(100))
    BEGIN
      SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Section.Name 
    FROM Section inner join DetailsMats ON Section.NumSection=DetailsMats.NumSection 
    WHERE DetailsMats.TechName or DetailsMats.GenName LIKE  "',job_no, '%"');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END $$`